# Overload a pointer to an overloaded function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers, overloading

If I try to define a pointer to an overloaded function

```
void myprint(int );
void myprint(const char* );
void (*funpointer)(int) = myprint;
```

the compiler understands that `funpointer` should point to the version of `myprint` that matches its arguments. Instead, I want `funpointer` to be overloaded as well.
I tried simply adding a couple lines like

```
void myprint(int );
void myprint(const char* );
void (*funpointer)(int);
void (*funpointer)(const char *);
void funpointer = myprint;
```

but then the compiler complains of conflicting declarations for `funpointer` (obviously).

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for? I would like the pointer to behave as an overloaded function. So I could call it as either `funpointer(1)` or `funpointer("Hey.")` and it would work as the respective version of `myprint`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing this?  Function pointers are for runtime polymorphism based on application state.  Plain old overloads work fine if, the only variance is the argument type.

If you want to be able to, say write a library that will call overloads defined later, in client code, do something like the following:

```
void foo(int x) { printf("int\n");}
void foo(const char* c){ printf("char*\n"); }

template <class T> void callfoo(T t) { foo(t); }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int x = 3;
    callfoo(x);

    const char* p = "Hello world";
    callfoo(p); 

    return 0;
}
```

This allows the lib to call overloads for types it is not actually aware of until link time.

Comment: if the decs above main were in lib.h, later code that includes it could do the following:

struct MYSTRUCT { double d; int x }
void foo (MYSTRUCT m) { printf ("mystruct\n"); }
 ... 
MYSTRUCT ms = { 3.14159, 6 };
foo(ms); 

and the lib would call your foo. 
caution, with this technique, you have to be very careful of implicit type conversions

Comment: sorry, that should be callfoo(ms), then the lib would call back to your foo(MYSTRUCT ms);

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is that `funpointer` alternates between several functions during runtime. These functions are overloaded to accept both integers and chars, and that's the problem I'm having. I  would rather not split these overloaded functions into regular ones (as that would require changing a lot of code elsewhere), but I think I'll have to go with that.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a way around it if you are, for instance, just parsing a file with multiple types of data. That's not what func ptrs are made for, and it is what overloads are made for. Instead of making, for instance, a "fooint" and "foochar" function, couldn't you just refactor the code you are calling this from to use the overloads?  If you have multiple sets of overloads, say, to handle each kind differently depending on app state, then one of the functor solutions above would probably work.

Answer (score 2):

No can do. You can't have two variables in the same scope with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer is a Type, it cannot be overloaded. Only functions can be overloaded.

There is no way to achieve overloading of a pointer in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with function pointers... the argument list is part of the type, so any given function pointer can only correspond to one specific overload at a time.  You might be able to fake it with function objects, though, depending on what you need to do.

```
struct MyPrint {
    void operator()(int i) { int_f(i); }
    void operator()(const char* c_str) { str_f(c_str); }

    std::function<void(int)> int_f;
    std::function<void(const char*) str_f;
};

void print_int(int i) { cout << i << endl; }
void print_string(const char* str) { cout << str << endl; }

int main() {
  MyPrint p;
  p.int_f = print_int;
  p.str_f = print_string;
  p(5);
  p("Hi");
}
```

You lose the ability to just overload by name; you can't add a `set_functions(f)` that takes a function name and extracts both versions of the function.  But as I showed, now you aren't limited to functions with the same name, or even just to functions.  The object is also bigger than it used to be, and likely involves some heap allocations.

Answer (score 0):

This might be considered "clunky", but you could do something like the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct funcptr_struct
{
    typedef T type;
    static type ptr;
};

template<> funcptr_struct<void(*)(int)>::type funcptr_struct<void(*)(int)>::ptr = myprint;
template<> funcptr_struct<void(*)(const char*)>::type funcptr_struct<void(*)(const char*)>::ptr = myprint;
```

You can then call each version of the `myprint` function using syntax like the following:

```
funcptr_struct<void(*)(int)>::ptr(5);
```